# I need to add a custom skillset to a Cognitive Search index, but it can't see my Azure Function app

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search

I've create an Azure Function App that I wish to use as a custom skillset. I can run this function and it seems good to go.  When I go to the portal and hit the Add Skillset page, I choose Custom Web API Skill - Azure Functions.  The drop down however doesn't show any Function Apps as available in the drop down.   What am I missing?

I've added the Search Service principal to Reader access on the Function App.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Did you verify that the function app and cognitive search are in same subscription? @frmrIntern

Comment: Because I am able to see the list of function apps for custom web api skill set without adding any reader roles too. [image](https://i.imgur.com/V1vGfkb.png) @frmrIntern

Comment: @frmrIntern what runtime stack you are using for function? python/.NET/Java/node.js?

Comment: Hi all, the function is in Python and they are in the same subscription.

Comment: Only dotnet runtime function apps are visible in the cognitive search dropdown. It seems that it supports only dotnet web Api functions. After a workaround on your issue, I achieved it by creating a custom web Api skillset with the help of `Json` code manually as shown [image](https://i.imgur.com/pMoNqvU.png). Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-defining-skillset#add-a-custom-skill). @frmrIntern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in the comments, it looks like that only `dotnet` azure function apps are supported for creating a skill set directly from the portal's cognitive search skill set dropdown.  After a workaround on it, I found an alternative which is creating a custom web Api skill set manually by adding Uri and specific `json` inputs and outputs as detailed in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-defining-skillset#add-a-custom-skill).

I've added the sample template under `skillset definition (Json)` to call an Azure `Python` runtime function by passing the function app `Url` in place `uri` property below as follows.

```bash
"skills": [
{
"@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
"name": "",
"description": "This skill calls an Azure function",
"context": "/document/orgs/*",
"uri": "https://pythoncognitive.azurewebsites.net",
"httpMethod": "POST",
"timeout": "PT60S",
"batchSize": 1000,
"inputs":[],
"outputs"[]
}
```

[image]

***Skillset added successfully:***

[image]

*Note:* You can also use `Rest Api` to create a skill set as given in [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-skillset).